# Building Boost unit test framework on Debian 8.3 ARM

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm trying to port a larger project to an embedded Linux system (Debian 8.3 ARM). The project requires Boost libraries newer than the system's Synaptic (1.55 vs. 1.58), so I'll need to build Boost from source. Usually I pick the most recent version, which was 1.60 when I downloaded things two weeks ago (current is 1.61).

The project contains test cases requiring `boost_unit_test_framework`. 
From the Boost docs I take it the calls (from the unzipped source directory) should be

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/home/tinyt/b160_clang \
--with-libraries=system,thread,<more lbraries>,\
boost_unit_test_framework,test_exec_monitor
./b2 install toolset=clang
```

and that ought to give me boost 1.60 in `~/b160_clang` (line breaks are not part of the command but inserted here for readability).
The problem is that b2 doesn't recognize `boost_unit_test_framework` or `unit_test_framework` as libraries and therefore doesn't build boost. 
If I just omit the library, my subset of boost libraries builds, but of course CMake fails because its `boost_unit_test_framework` requirement is not met.

Are there any other libraries that I ought to include?
Does the sequence of libraries matter?
Should I link to ar somewhere along the way?

The CMake generally seems to be OK, my build environment for the project is a x86 Debian 8.3 machine where things work fine. The difference is that there is enough room for a full install here.

Running clang 3.5 and CMake 3.0.2, same as the functional desktop system. 
Most likely there is not enough space on the embedded target system to build the entire boost library AND have free space for my project app.

Am I missing further dependencies of `boost_unit_test_framework`? 
Is there a catch in how to specify the library for installation? 
Is the unit test framework header-only so I can just copy the headers manually?

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

I've just tried running `bjam --prefix=/... --with-<...>` for all the libraries I want to build with. The output was the same as before:

```
error: wrong library name 'boost_unit_test_framework' in the --with-<library> option.
```

The same is true if I omit the prefix `boost_`.

Comment: Running `bjam --show-libraries` I see one of the library names listed is "test". Try using that for a library name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incorrect name to specify the library.

You [may run](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install)

```
bjam --show-libraries
```

to obtain a list of names of the libraries that require compilation.

For example, with boost 1.58, I get the following (trimmed) output:

```
...updated 1 target...
The following libraries require building:
    - atomic
    - chrono
    - container
    - context
    - coroutine
    - date_time
    - exception
    - filesystem
    - graph
    - graph_parallel
    - iostreams
    - locale
    - log
    - math
    - mpi
    - program_options
    - python
    - random
    - regex
    - serialization
    - signals
    - system
    - test
    - thread
    - timer
    - wave
```

Inspecting that, I can see there is a library named `test`. That's the one you're looking for. Hence, your command line to perform the build should contain:

```
--with-libraries=system,thread,<more libraries>,test
```

Comment: That's what I feared after having to add the CMake dependency `boost_unit_test_framework` despite the library being called `libboost_unit_test_framework`; for system, you need to specify `system` in CMake AND boost bootstrap list, and the file is called `libboost_system` as well... 
Works like a charm. Thanks for the inspection instruction, too!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at boost bcp. Using bcp you can specify what parts of boost you actually want and only "build" those.
Bcp lets you wrap those parts in a separate namespace, which might be handy, depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks! From what I read, bcp needs to be built from boost sources, too... Can I do that without building boost (is that why you quoted the word "build")? Or is your main suggestion to create the library sources for ARM on the x86, move those and build them much like I would the "full" boost lib?